# GridsearchCV() gives optimum criterion for Decision Tree should be entropy, but why am I getting better accuracy with Gini?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, scikit-learn, cart, gini

I ran this code

```
sc = StandardScaler()
pca = decomposition.PCA()
decisiontree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('sc',sc),
                      ('pca',pca),
                      ('decisiontree', decisiontree)])

n_components = list(range(1,x.shape[1]+1,1))
criterion = ['gini', 'entropy']
max_depth = [4,6,8,12]

parameters = dict(pca__n_components = n_components,
                 decisiontree__criterion = criterion,
                 decisiontree__max_depth = max_depth)

clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters)
clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)

# Viewing The Best Parameters

print('Best Criterion:', clf.best_estimator_.get_params()['decisiontree__criterion'])
print('Best max_depth:', clf.best_estimator_.get_params()['decisiontree__max_depth'])
print('Best Number Of Components:', clf.best_estimator_.get_params()['pca__n_components'])
print(); print(clf.best_estimator_.get_params()['decisiontree'])

This gives me an output as below:

Best Criterion: entropy
Best max_depth: 6
Best Number Of Components: 15

DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='entropy', max_depth=6,
                       max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False,
                       random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

However when I then try scaling features, then applying PCA & then Decision tree using all above arguments except criterion = 'gini' I get aa better accuracy score.

```
clf2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=6,
                       max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False,
                       random_state=None, splitter='best')
clf2.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print(clf2.score(X_test, Y_test))
```

This gives a result as 0.5974025974025974 where as with entropy it gives 0.5324675324675324. Then why GridsearchCV suggests a non-optimum criterion?

Answer (score 0):

There was a somehowe similar question once posted on SO, but not exactly the same, but we can derive something from it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530761/cross-validation-with-grid-search-returns-worse-results-than-default

The question is, if you did train/test split before applying the GridSearchCV.
Not Splitting before applying GridSearchCV is data leakage,
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67740/does-it-make-sense-to-use-train-test-split-and-cross-validation-when-using-grids
From your code I cannot judge if you did that before, because GridSearch is just for Hyperparameter tuning and should not see the whole data set. If you do a proper train/test split before applying Gridsearch and your regular fit method, there should normally no problem.

In Addition, Gini and Entropy results normally near each other, as they only disagree on splitting in only rough 2 % in all cases which should lead to mostly near accuracy.

https://www.unine.ch/files/live/sites/imi/files/shared/documents/papers/Gini_index_fulltext.pdf

So I can assure you, that the information gain criteria is not the root of the problem, neither is the GridSearchCV, it depends if you have done a proper split before pushing data into GridSearchCV. At least that is my feeling here.